# C++ STD libraries in C

Tags: c++, c

as the title suggests I am attempting to mix C and C++ source files in a project.

My project has the following files

```
.
├── comms
│   ├── can.c
├── config_parsing
│   ├── config_parser.c
│   ├── file_operations.c
├── main.cpp
├── scheduler.c
├── signal_handler.c
├── thread_health.c
└── utilities
    ├── logger.c
    ├── ring_buffer.c
    ├── string_operations.c
    ├── time_conversions.c
```

In eclipse this compiles, builds and deploys. I am adding code from a vendor that I cannot share as it is purchased code. They have code for SSL which has `.h` and `.c` files. In the header file we have

```
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

In the C file we have many instances of `std::vector<unsigned char>`, `std::string`. This does not compile.

I am using a Yocto generated SDK to build my application and I can confirm the appropriate files exist in my include paths

```
/opt/fsl-imx-fb/5.10-hardknott/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/10.2.0
```

When looking online I see how to properly include C header files in a C++ application but I cannot seem to find out how to use `std::vector` in a C file. If needed I can share images of the eclipse compiler/build settings.

The application builds in Ubuntu.

Image to show[image]

Comment: I'm surprised you were given *.c files if you paid. Typically, I would expect a header and pre-compiled dynamic library files. But you're saying that you got full access to their IP.

Comment: ??? There is no proper way to include standard libraries like `<vector>` in a C file. There is limited overlap between C and C++. The C++ standard libraries definitely aren't one of them. You need to communicate through a common ABI.

Comment: You can't use `std::vector` in C code.  Any code using `std::vector` will need to be compiled as C++ code.

Comment: That is _obviously_ C++. Are you sure they aren't `.H` and `.C` files? I don't like the use of case-sensitive filenames but have seen that convention for C++ somewhere or other ...

Comment: _"In eclipse this compiles, builds and deploys"_  and _"The application builds in Ubuntu"_ is all good, but in what environment combo _doesn't_ it build? Windows?

Comment: @Useless yeah, won't work on windows..or on a flash drive FAT file system even if using Linux..they would become lowercase

Comment: I have used Yocto to build an image for an IMX6. When using the exported SDK it fails to build.

Comment: You could _try_ compiling them as `c++`. You could rename them from `.c` to `.cpp`. Or, change the build to add options `-x c++` to force treatment as c++ regardless of the `.c` extension. Either with `g++ -x c++` or `gcc -x c++`

Comment: Renaming to .cpp and .hpp works. So I will explore this -x c++ suggestion

Comment: If the extension is always lower-case as you suggest, the difference must be that the working builds already know they should compile that file as C++, and the failing build either believes it should compile it as C or guesses that based on the extension. There's no way it will ever compile successfully as C

Comment: Rename to `.cpp` is needed (or `-x c++`). But, you could leave `.h` as `.h` as `.hpp` is just a nicety. In fact, I've seen a lot of code that has c++ header files with a `.h` extension

Comment: @Useless I figured that it would never compile successfully. Thank you for confirming.

Comment: @CraigEstey thank you for the tips. I will take this back to the vendors as ask if they have any special settings to get this building.

Comment: Distributing c++ code in files with the extension `.c` is cruel.

Comment: To make the vendor library callable from C, some of the public API calls will need to be built with `extern "C"` I presume this has been done because otherwise you'd have linking issues.

Comment: @CraigEstey if you want to provide an answer, I will gladly accept it! The -c c++ option has worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you want to provide an answer, I will gladly accept it! The -c c++ option has worked! –
> Michael

It is pretty clear that the code in the `.c` files is C++ code and *not* C code. This is evidenced by the `#include` directives you found:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

The compiler front end (e.g. `gcc` or `g++`) will try to determine the language to use based on the file extension (e.g. `.c` --> C and `.cpp` --> C++).

So, even if we compile with `g++` it will still compile as C because of the `.c` extension (vs. prescanning the content of the file).

So, there are a few remedies:

1. Rename all `.c` files that are actually C++ code to `.cpp`
2. Add `-x c++` to the compiler command line for the affected files to force it to interpret the files as C++ code. This works for *either* front end: `gcc` or `g++`

Ordinarily, (1) would be the chosen method *if* the files were "owned" by you. That is, fix it the right way *once*.

If we could convince the 3rd party vendor to do this, that would be best (i.e.) the vendor applies (1).

However, if the vendor won't/can't do this and you/your company renames the files, the problem returns anytime you take in a new version from the vendor.

So, a cleaner (i.e. one time fix) is to do (2) and modify *your* build/Makefile to add the `-x c++`

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use `std::vector` in a C file, because C doesn't have namespaces, classes, or templates.

The closest it gets is that C++ code could get a pointer to the vector's contents, and pass the pointer to C code, which could read or write data there, because C does have pointers.